# What is the order when doing process elimination on algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm often getting confused about the order when doing elemination process on algebraic equation to the point of not being confident when solving algebraic equation, I have done some search, even ask on IRC, but mostly it's only talk about simplifying algebraic expression or some answer that order of operation has nothing to do with it.

I know that there's rules to follow, but for me it seems like reverse of PEMDAS.

For example $a + b \times c = d$, If I want to do process of elemination I should  do it to the last operation first: $-a + a + b \times c = -a + d$ not $a + b \times (c \times 1/c) = d \times 1/c$ because according to PEMDAS, addition comes after multiplication, it's like LIFO(Last In First Out). But I think I'm mostly wrong because the guy on IRC obviously know more than me, but I can't be convinced with just 'yes or no' answer.

And it would be helpful if there's any source that explain the rule explicitly.

Comment: Why no one answer my basic question, while other complicated question was immediately answered. I really need help, I don't have any confidence when working with algebraic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a + bc = d
Multiply both sides by 1/c to get
d/c = (a + bc)/c = a/c + b.
Notice the parenthesis.

FIFO is computer think and do not think computer think
will help you with math.  It will not.  It is a disavantage.